# How to remove unnecessary characters from string?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, character, special-characters

There is a problem in character when I fetch data from database.

`doesn�t`

`It�s`

I have tried to remove it using `str_replace` function but it's not working.

```
str_replace('�','',$str);
```

The encoding is

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

How can i solve these problem?

Comment: it must have to do with the encoding.

Comment: Whats the encoding in your database fields? What is the encoding of your php script?

Comment: In have seen similar situations when a system uses a simple non-Unicode encoding and is given input copied from a tool like MS Word that uses Unicode quotes: U+2018, etc. Can you chang your page's encoding?

Comment: @Jari <meta charset="UTF-8"  />

Comment: you check directly in your database...what is this exact character then do str_replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `utf8_encode()` function.

It will remove that characters

```
utf8_decode('doesn�t');  // doesnt
```

this is not good because it removes `'` from `doesn't`

**OR**

Just update your Meta tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

to

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
```

**Output**

`doesn't`

`It's`

Answer (score 3):

no need to remove those character, Try to use `htmlentities()` or `utfdecode()` function to display those properly

This is because character encoding

Answer (score 2):

Just removing the "�"s would give you wrong output. For instance, the string is probably `doesn't`, removing � from `doesn�t` gives you `doesnt` which is wrong.

What you should do is fix your encoding. You are probably saving or retrieving the strings in an encoding different from your code.